# jline keep prompt at the bottom

Tags: java, shell, command-line, jline

I am using [`jline`](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) and I have a neat `ConsoleReader` and everything works great. However, if you are typing something into the the prompt and there is output on stdout (from another thread), the output splits the word/command that you are typing.

How can I keep the `jline` prompt at the bottom of the terminal?

I am using `jline` 1, but I am open to using `jline` 2 if it is stable enough.

Comment: The library is purportedly design to handle console input; I don't see how it can handle console output. The problem is that console I/O events are asynchronous (in your case). Maybe, you need to store the console output in a temporary buffer while performing the input and display the output from the buffer once the input has been done.

Comment: Maybe you need to look for Curses library for Java http://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/, http://sourceforge.net/projects/enigma-shell/, or http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-12/02-qa-1220-console.html which allows you to reposition your console input/output cursor

Answer (score 6):

Finally figured this out... here's what you do. First, define these functions:

```
private ConsoleReader console = ...;
private CursorBuffer stashed;

private void stashLine() {
    this.stashed = this.console.getCursorBuffer().copy();
    try {
        this.console.getOutput().write("\u001b[1G\u001b[K");
        this.console.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ignore
    }
}

private void unstashLine() {
    try {
        this.console.resetPromptLine(this.console.getPrompt(),
          this.stashed.toString(), this.stashed.cursor);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // ignore
    }
}
```

Then when you want to output new data, first invoke `stashLine()` to save the current console input, then output whatever new lines of output, then invoke `unstashLine()` to restore it.

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal.